# Xcode warning: "directory not found for option"

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml

I am getting two strange warnings on Xcode after changing the directory of my project (the parent directory, not any of the folders within the working directory). They state "directory not found for option" about my /Build/Products/Release directory.

I am working on a C++ project in Xcode using the SFML game engine.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have had this error and had different fixes, but none worked for me. In the end using Product->Clean in the Xcode menu cleared up the two warnings for me.